# How can i add generator to fullfilment section in Dialogflow CX nodejs api

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to doc. there is no way. Or i didn't find it.

```
 interface IFulfillment {

                        /** Fulfillment messages */
                        messages?: (google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.IResponseMessage[]|null);

                        /** Fulfillment webhook */
                        webhook?: (string|null);

                        /** Fulfillment returnPartialResponses */
                        returnPartialResponses?: (boolean|null);

                        /** Fulfillment tag */
                        tag?: (string|null);

                        /** Fulfillment setParameterActions */
                        setParameterActions?: (google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Fulfillment.ISetParameterAction[]|null);

                        /** Fulfillment conditionalCases */
                        conditionalCases?: (google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.Fulfillment.IConditionalCases[]|null);

                        /** Fulfillment advancedSettings */
                        advancedSettings?: (google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3.IAdvancedSettings|null);

                        /** Fulfillment enableGenerativeFallback */
                        enableGenerativeFallback?: (boolean|null);
                    }
```

[In Google Cloud Console , i can add generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fb82.png)